# How to drag an Openseadragon canvas with mouse middle wheel button

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouse, fabricjs, openseadragon

I am using Openseadragon library with fabricjs overlay. I have a case where I want to drag the canvas but instead of mouse primary button, I want to drag it with middle mouse button press. Could anyone please help me get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSeadragon doesn't have a flag for that, but you can easily build it using the MouseTracker. Here's an example (coded from memory and not tested, but it should give you the idea).

```
var drag;

var mouseTracker = new OpenSeadragon.MouseTracker({
  element: viewer.container, 
  nonPrimaryPressHandler: function(event) {
    if (event.button === 1) { // Middle
      drag = { 
        lastPos: event.position.clone()
      };
    }
  },
  moveHandler: function(event) {
    if (drag) {
      var deltaPixels = drag.lastPos.minus(event.position);
      var deltaPoints = viewer.viewport.deltaPointsFromPixels(deltaPixels);
      viewer.viewport.panBy(deltaPoints);
      drag.lastPos = event.position.clone();
    }
  },
  nonPrimaryReleaseHandler: function(event) {
    if (event.button === 1) {
      drag = null;
    }
  }
});
```

**EDIT**: I had a bug in the example code above; fixed.

Comment: I am able to drag the canvas with mouse middle wheel button but canvas movement is very fast.

Comment: Here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/t5kUse2ztmdyoDKTyAjZ?p=preview

Comment: I see! I made the mistake in my first example of converting the position to viewport coordinates too soon; the fact that the viewport was moving around caused the points to be inaccurate. I'm now saving the position in web coordinates and converting to viewport at the last minute, which creates the right result. I also had the `minus` backward so it was going in the wrong direction. Let me know if this works now!

Comment: Excellent; glad to hear it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @iangilman 's answer...

To improve the user experience when the middle button is released outside the MouseTracker's element while dragging, causing the nonPrimaryReleaseHandler to never get called, the pointer can be captured...something like this:

```js
var trackerElement = viewer.container;
var drag;

function capturePointer(event) {
  if (OpenSeadragon.MouseTracker.havePointerCapture) {
    if (OpenSeadragon.MouseTracker.havePointerEvents) {
      // Can throw InvalidPointerId
      try {
        trackerElement.setPointerCapture(event.originalEvent.pointerId);
      } catch () {
        //
      }
    } else {
        trackerElement.setCapture(true);
    }
  }
}

function releasePointer(event) {
  if (OpenSeadragon.MouseTracker.havePointerCapture) {
    if (OpenSeadragon.MouseTracker.havePointerEvents) {
      // Can throw InvalidPointerId
      try {
        trackerElement.releasePointerCapture(event.originalEvent.pointerId);
      } catch () {
        //
      }
    } else {
        trackerElement.releaseCapture();
    }
  }
}

var mouseTracker = new OpenSeadragon.MouseTracker({
  element: trackerElement,
  nonPrimaryPressHandler: function(event) {
    if (event.button === 1) { // Middle
      capturePointer(event);
      drag = {
        lastPos: event.position.clone()
      };
    }
  },
  moveHandler: function(event) {
    if (drag) {
      var deltaPixels = drag.lastPos.minus(event.position);
      var deltaPoints = viewer.viewport.deltaPointsFromPixels(deltaPixels);
      viewer.viewport.panBy(deltaPoints);
      drag.lastPos = event.position.clone();
    }
  },
  nonPrimaryReleaseHandler: function(event) {
    if (event.button === 1) {
      releasePointer(event);
      drag = null;
    }
  }
});
```